# Adding a new row to kable table in R to LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, knitr, kable

I've been trying to add a row to an existing summary statistics table obtained with `knitr::kable`.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
stats %>% 
kable(format = 'latex', booktabs = TRUE, valign = 't') %>% 
pack_rows("Var1", 1, 4) %>% 
pack_rows("Var2", 5, 8) %>% 
save_kable('export.tex'))
```

The output should look as follows:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{lrr}
\toprule
 & Mean & Standard deviation\\
\midrule
\addlinespace[0.3em]
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Var1}}\\
\hspace{1em}A & 1.5 & 0.34\\
\hspace{1em}B & 2.44 & 0.44\\
\hspace{1em}C & 2.56 & 0.44\\
\hspace{1em}D & 1.22 & 0.39\\
\addlinespace[0.3em]
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Var2}}\\
\hspace{1em}A &1.66 & 1.33\\
\hspace{1em}B & 1.96 & 1.22\\
\hspace{1em}C & 1.44 & 1.24\\
\hspace{1em}D & 1.68 & 1.55\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Observations}}\\
\hspace{1em}A & 503\\
\hspace{1em}B & 606\\
\hspace{1em}C & 705\\
\hspace{1em}D & 104\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

In other words, I'm looking to add the rows where the observation number should appear as integers:

```
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Observations}}\\
\hspace{1em}A & 503\\
\hspace{1em}B & 606\\
\hspace{1em}C & 705\\
\hspace{1em}D & 104\\
```

Comment: Could you include the output of `dput(stats)` in the question to make it reproducible?